# Hide "Trending" on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I just clicked on a "Trending" item displayed on the right-hand side in Facebook, and then wasted half an hour reading that article.

**How can I disable this new source of distractions?**

I'm using Firefox, but if there is a fix specific to Chrome, I could switch to that.

Comment: Aka "Trending Articles", "Trending Topics", "Trending Videos", ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on: https://superuser.com/a/319322

Step 1 : Open Firefox, Go to 'Firefox' menu at the top-left of the browser.

```
Firefox --> Help --> Troubleshooting Information --> Show Folder
```

(it's a button next to "Profile folder")

Step 2 : Create a folder named chrome in your profile folder

Step 3 : Create a css file userContent.css

Step 4 : Copy the following code to the file userContent.css

Step 5 :

```
@-moz-document domain(facebook.com) {
    #pagelet_trending_tags_and_topics {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Step 7 : Restart the browser

(How do I find that it has to be "pagelet_trending_tags_and_topics"? I used DOM Inspector plugin, it has a clicker, you can click on anything to find out its name.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for both Firefox and Chrome is the **FB Purity** browser add-on, it has a built in option to hide the "**Trending**" box.

Steps to get rid of the Trending Box:

1. Install the free add-on here: **http://install.fbpurity.com**
2. Visit any Facebook page and click the "**FBP**" link in the top nav bar to open the **FB Purity** options screen.
3. Tick the Hide "**Trending Topics**" option.
4. Click the "**Save & Close**" button.

You should now no longer see the "**Trending**" box.